# Quotient of Coxeter group

Tags: gr.group-theory, coxeter-groups

Since the group $G := \langle a, b \ | \ a^2, b^3, (ab)^7, [a,b]^{10} \rangle$ seems to have resisted attacks of some powerful programs, I will turn to a group that seems to be a bit easier to analyse. The group

$$H := \langle a, b, c \ | \ a^2, b^2, c^2, (ab)^2, (ac)^3, (bc)^7, (abc)^{19} \rangle$$

only has one of the simple groups that are a quotient of $G$, $J_1$. Therefore it seems it will be easier to analyse. 
Adding the relation $(abcbc)^i$ gives the trivial group for all $i$ less than 25 except for 15, where it gives $J_1$. What is the group

$$I := \langle a, b, c \ | \ a^2, b^2, c^2, (ab)^2, (ac)^3, (bc)^7, (abc)^{19}, (abcbc)^{25} \rangle?$$

I have checked on magma using knuth bendix, and it takes too long, so magma stops the calculation.

Comment: "Adding the relation" ??   Please edit.   Also, I added a tag.

Comment: $J_1$ is not the only simple quotient of $G$. Another one is ${\rm PSL}(2,113)$.

Comment: Your group $I$ is trivial. I did a coset enumeration over the subgroup $\langle abcbc \rangle$ and got index $1$.

Comment: @Derek: Indeed. -- Checking this is even quite quick -- in GAP this takes less than half a minute on my laptop.

Comment: Taking the relation $(abcbc)^{26}$ instead of $(abcbc)^{25}$, the group is still trivial, though the verification is somewhat harder --  making the GAP job grow to something like 700MB before returning the answer that there is only one coset.

Comment: Ok, so how do we get the quotient PSL(2,113)? Also, it would be nice to know what happens when we take the relation (abcbc)^i for i=27, 28, and 29. If we found the structure of this group, and proved that the only simple quotients are J1 and PSL(2,113), it might be easier to prove that taking those relations yields the trivial group.

Answer (score 13):

As you may know, in the family of groups

$H^{m,n,p} := \langle a, b, c \ | \ a^2, b^2, c^2, (ab)^2, (ac)^m, (bc)^n, (abc)^p \rangle$

considered by Coxeter, there is only one remaining case for which finiteness has not been decided, $H^{3,7,19}$, which is your group $H$. It is possible that $H \cong J_1 \times {\rm PSL}(2,113)$, since only two finite simple quotients are known. The kernel of the homomorphism onto $J_1$ is perfect. I haven't quite proved it, but I think the kernel onto ${\rm PSL}(2,113)$ is also perfect.

A homomorphism onto ${\rm PSL}(2,113)$ is induced by the map onto ${\rm SL}(2,113)$

$$a \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{rr}58& 57\\ 50& 55\end{array}\right),
b \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{rr}55& 69\\ 2& 58\end{array}\right),
c \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{rr}100& 67\\ 43& 13\end{array}\right).$$

The image of $abcbc$ under this map has order $57$.

With the ACE coset enumerator, I have been able to show that adding the extra relation $(abcbc)^n$ gives the trivial group for $n=25,26,27,28,29$, but I've got stuck on $n=30$.

Comment: Oh, cool, I stumbled upon an open problem! Adding the relation (abcbc)^30 at least gives J1, so it will be harder.

Comment: @Derek, that is a fantastic answer. Where did Coxeter consider this family of groups? What's so special about the ones that are left? (Maybe I should ask this as a separate question on MO...)

Comment: @Nick Gill: My paper with George Havas, G. Havas and D.F. Holt. On Coxeter's families of group presentations. Journal of Algebra 324 (2010), 1076--1082 (which you can find on my webpage) describes the current state of knowledge of several families of groups considered by Coxeter, and includes references. I am not aware of any further advances since then.

Comment: @Derek, I looked at the paper. Am I being dumb or do you actually prove that the group $H^{3,8,13}$ is finite? (You say in the answer above that the status of this group is unresolved, but your paper seems to deal with it. I could be wrong, though, because you write the presentations differently in the paper than in this answer and I'm not certain things are equivalent.)

Comment: @Nick: No, I'm being dumb, not you! I only looked at the introduction to the paper and not at its contents! Yes, we proved that $H^{3,8,13}$ is finite - it's effectively the same proof as for the $(2,3,13;4)$ group. I will edit the post.

Comment: How would someone prove that the group is finite/infinite? I have an idea, which is that if the group H(3,7,19)=PSL(2,113)*J1, then the order of abcbc would be 285 (unless there are other ways to get PSL(2,113)).

Comment: Also the image of $abcbcbc$ has order 840 in $J_1 \times {\rm PSL}(2,113)$, so the subgroup $\langle abcbcbc \rangle$ would have index $150770928$ if $G \cong J_1 \times {\rm PSL}(2,113)$, and then coset enumeration should work on a machine with lots of memory. But that has been tried with no success to date.

Comment: Ok, what is the presentation of PSL(2,113) in terms of H(3,7,19)? Or the presentation of J1*PSL(2,113)?